# How can I find all results on a date between two dates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

In a SQL Server table there are two dates: a start datetime and an end datetime. Now I want to search for all results on a date time. For example this table:

```
id|name|starttime|endtime
1|Peter|2014-07-22 07:00|2014-07-22 15:00
2|John|2014-07-22 08:00|2014-07-22 17:00
3|Martin|2014-07-22 07:30|2014-07-22 12:00
```

Now I want to now all results who match on 2014-07-22 07:50

I take a look to `BETWEEN` and `DATEDIFF` but think that doesn't work for it.

Comment: Hint: You want to find results where your date occurs after starttime and before endtime.

Comment: Yes this is the conclusion, but how I can reach this goal?

Comment: Read it and break down the logic into smaller parts, then it's very simple.

Comment: Yes you're right, it was very simple :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whats wrong with 
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE @Parameter BETWEEN startTime AND endTime ?

Comment: If I set the startdate and enddate where I can set my datetime I'am looking for?

Comment: Ok - I think you are asking "I don't know how to pass a parameter to a piece of SQL in order to compare its value with data held in the database" ? In which case the answer depends very much on what tools you are using - SQL Enterprise Manager ? .net programming language ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Select *
From YourTable
Where StartDate <= @YourDate
  and EndDate >= @YourDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down your logic, you want to find results where `your date occurs after starttime` **and** `your date occurs before endtime`.

Breaking it down further, you have 2 conditions:

1. YourDate > starttime
2. YourDate < endtime

So now we can write our SQL:

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE @YourDate > starttime
AND @YourDate < endtime
```

Note that you didn't specify if the time you specify can occur exactly on the starttime or end time. Of so, replace `<` with `<=` and `>` with `>=`.

There are other ways to achieve the same goal but this shows how to break up a problem into smaller parts which is often the path to a solution when writing SQL queries.